# Accidentally deleted /usr/bin/env... anyway to rebuild it?

Tags: ubuntu

Dumb mistake. I accidentally deleted /usr/bin/env.

Is there anyway I can regenerate that file?

This is in Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env` is part of `coreutils`.

```
apt-get install coreutils
```

should restore the file.

Note that package search at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ search packages for path names.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up: would it be possible to copy the file from a different server that had the same version of Ubuntu installed, or is it modified on some way?

Comment: @BenjaminAllison It's a command, so it should be fine to copy from one install to another.

Comment: I'd add, you may need to use apt-get --reinstall install coreutils, since as far as dpkg/apt is concerned, the package is still there. It dosen't account for this flavour of human error, so you may need to force it.